# Extract Entered Data from Form (PHP)

Tags: php, forms, validation

I'm currently taking a course as part of my web design programs, and my final project requires creating a validating registration form. While the form validates the data correctly, I can't get it to save any data that's entered once the user submits it. I've been instructed by the course to use the 'extract' function to repopulate the form inputs, but I've had a lot of issues using this in the past as well. The following is the code for my form:

```
<?php
$labels = array("first_name" => "First Name*:", 
                "last_name" => "Last Name*:",
                "company" => "Company*:",
                "address" => "Address*:",
                "city" => "City*:",
                "province_state" => "Province/State*:",
                "postal_zip" => "Postal/Zip Code*:",
                "phone" => "Telephone:",
                "fax" => "Fax:",
                "email" => "Email Address*:",
                "comments" => "Comments:");
$submit = "Submit";
?>

...

<form method="post">
<table class='form'>
<?php
foreach($labels as $label => $field)
{
    if($label == 'postal_zip')
    {
        echo "<tr><td class='label'><label for='$label'>$field</label></td>
        <td class='input'><input type='text' name='$label' maxlength='9'></td></tr>";
    }
    if($label == 'phone' or $label == 'fax')
    {
        echo "<tr><td class='label'><label for='$label'>$field</label></td>
        <td class='input'><input type='text' name='$label' maxlength='14'></td></tr>";
    }
    if($label == 'comments')
    {
        echo "<tr><td class='label'><label for='$label'>$field</label></td>
        <td class='input'><textarea name='$label' cols='30' rows='5'></textarea></td></tr>";
    }
    else
    {
        if($label != 'postal_zip' && $label != 'phone' && $label != 'fax' && 'comments')
        {
            echo "<tr><td class='label'><label for='$label'>$field</label></td>
            <td class='input'><input type='text' name='$label' value='$value'></td></tr>";
        }
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "<tr><td></td>
        <td><input type='hidden' name='submitted' value='yes'>
        <input type='submit' name='$submit' value='$submit'></td>";
?>
</table>
</form>
```

And the following is my validation code.

```
<?php
$message = "";
if(isset($_POST['submitted']) and $_POST['submitted'] == 'yes')
{
    foreach($_POST as $field => $value)
    {
        if(empty($value) or !empty($value))
        {
            $email_patt = "/^.+@.+\\..+$/";
            $name_patt = "/^[A-Za-z' -]{1,50}/";
            $addr_patt = "/^[A-Za-z0-9 .,'-]{1,50}$/";
            $postal_patt = "/^[A-Za-z0-9-]{1,10}$/";
            $phone_patt =  "/^[0-9)(xX -]{7,20}$/";
            if(preg_match("/first_name/i",$field))
            {
                if(!preg_match($name_patt,$value))
                {
                    $error_array[] = "Please enter a valid first name.";
                }
            }
            if(preg_match("/last_name/i",$field))
            {
                if(!preg_match($name_patt,$value))
                {
                    $error_array[] = "Please enter a valid last name.";
                }
            }
            if(preg_match("/address/i",$field))
            {
                if(!preg_match($addr_patt,$value))
                {
                    $error_array[] = "Please enter a valid address.";
                }
            }
            if(preg_match("/company/i",$field))
            {
                if(!preg_match($addr_patt,$value))
                {
                    $error_array[] = "Please enter a valid company name.";
                }
            }
            if(preg_match("/city/i",$field))
            {
                if(!preg_match($addr_patt,$value))
                {
                    $error_array[] = "Please enter a valid city.";
                }
            }
            if(preg_match("/country/i",$field))
            {
                if(!preg_match($addr_patt,$value))
                {
                    $error_array[] = "Please enter a valid address.";
                }
            }
            if(preg_match("/postal_zip/i",$field))
            {
                if(!preg_match($postal_patt,$value))
                {
                    $error_array[] = "Please enter a valid postal/zip code.";
                }
            }
            if(preg_match("/email/i",$field))
            {
                if(!preg_match($email_patt,$value))
                {
                    $error_array[] = "Please enter a valid email address.";
                }
            }
        }
        $good_data[$field] = strip_tags(trim($value));
    }
    if(@sizeof($error_array) >0)
    {
        $message = "<ul class='error'>";
        foreach($error_array as $value)
        {
            $message .= "<li>$value</li>";
        }
        $message .= "</ul>";
        extract($good_data);
        include "contact_form.php";
        exit();
    }
    else 
    {
        header('location: success.html');
    }
}
else
{
    include "contact_form.php";
}
?>
```

Currently, I have all of the $_POST values put into the array $good_data, and using print_r in the validation code, I get a list of all of the fields and values entered by the user (though it does include all inputs on the page). Is there a simple way to put these values in each field?

Comment: all your validations will fail some valid data - think carefully when doing validation

Comment: I should also mention that I tried adding the value=' ".$value." ' field to my input fields and defined them under the $_POST[$value], but this didn't seem to work either.

Comment: Always try to avoid using the `extract()` function. Its a horrible concept and should probably be removed from the language

Comment: value= $_POST[$label] in the loop

Comment: Question: `if(empty($value) or !empty($value))` this will always be TRUE, so why have an IF there atall.

Comment: Lord above where did you find this tutorial `if(preg_match("/first_name/i",$field))` OVERKILL

Comment: What Dagon suggested worked, and now it keeps all of the data entered. I am getting a notice for each field though, which is a bit annoying.

Comment: What notice are you getting

Comment: 'Notice: Undefined index: first_name in...' this is repeated for each line I have. Each line of code currently has the following:
echo "<tr><td class='label'><label for='$label'>$field</label></td>
   <td class='input'><input type='text' name='$label' value=' ".strip_tags(trim($_POST[$label]))." '></td></tr>"

Comment: on first load none of the values will exist

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought. Should I just suppress notices and leave it as it is? It works perfectly after being submitted the first time.

Comment: do you want the "get it done and move on" opinion or the "best practice" one?

Comment: At this point, get it done lol. Thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Dagon for the answer to my question. By adding $_POST[$field] to the value of each field, it retains the data and functions properly.